# Kindle Fire Keyboard Buttons

Tags: android, ime, kindle-fire

I have an EditText field in my app:

```
           <EditText                    
                android:id="@+id/task_buy_edit_mass_editText1"
                android:minWidth="100dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone" >

            </EditText>
```

The problem is that on my Kindle Fire, the keyboard that appears when the user wants to edit the `EditText` has no Done button, just a button that hides the soft keyboard

[image]

That wouldn't be a problem if I could intercept the 'hide keyboard' button that I highlighted on the above screenshot. However, it doesn't seem to trigger the `OnEditorActionListener` I've attached to the `EditText`, so I'm a bit stuck what to do aside from having my own 'Done' button in my actual layout to take focus away from the EditText, hide the keyboard and make any changes that result from the number being changed

Is there a way to intercept the 'hide keyboard' button, or is there some alternative solution?

Incidentally, I have a regular EditText view elsewhere in my app that has no imeOptions nor specifies inputType and that does have a Return key

Here's the rest of the code for reference:

```
        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT || actionId==EditorInfo.IME_NULL || event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION || event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    closeKeyboard(v, done_button);              
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }});

            // set done button for keyboards without correct IME options
            final EditText finalEditText = editText;

            editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {                     
                    done_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {                               
                            closeKeyboard(finalEditText, v);
                        }});
                    done_button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return false;
                }                   
            });
```

.

```
        private void closeKeyboard(TextView v, View buttonv){
                demand.setAmount(Double.parseDouble((v.getText().toString()))); // update the game

                // close keyboard
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);                       
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);                       
                v.clearFocus();
                buttonv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions, and you have not asked a question. IMEs do not have to honor `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`, and so while you may be seeing this on the Fire, the problem is more general than that.

Comment: I know. I'm looking for a solution for the Kindle Fire. I edited my answer to make it clearer exactly what I was asking

Comment: You can try adding android:inputType="textMultiLine" and android:singleLine="true" to the EditText, however, I've found that this causes problems on newer Jelly Bean devices.

Answer (score 1):

`android:inputType="textMultiLine"` and `android:singleLine="true"` as @James Wald indicated works.

EDIT:
Doing the above will make it the EditText multi line. Instead `android:imeOptions="actionGo"` worked for my purposes on all devices (AFAIK).

Comment: android:imeOptions="actionGo" is more appropriate, use this :)